# Adding iOS device to scheme

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been tasked with transferring an app to an ipod. I'm a web developer with no knowledge of xcode or ios development. I have a list of instructions to follow.

I have the code, including a .workspace file. This all opens up fine in Xcode. In my instructions I need to be able to select the staging scheme. Problem is when I select staging there is no ios device listed next to it....there's only an option for my 64 bit mac. If I got to the scheme named Live I see an option for administrators Ipod.

Any idea how I can add the ipod to the staging scheme?

Comment: First, make sure you have a backup. Then you can [try to set](http://db.tt/dVagZ3RI) this target to be iOs target.

Comment: Mines already set to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top bar: Product -> Scheme

Comment: Any more info? It's really not obvious what needs doing?

Comment: In the scheme list, do you see 'staging' ?

Comment: Ahhhhh - found it....I needed to set the executable dropdown to my app. Now I'm seeing it! Thanks!